# How to load CSS and JS files of a website using UIWebViews in Xcode 7.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiwebview, swift2

I'm new to `Swift` programming and I'm trying to load the web content of a website into my app using `UIWebView`. But all I get is the skeleton of the webpage i.e. the `html`. How should I load the `css` and `javascript` of the website?

This is my ViewController.swift file.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.smartanalyzers.com")

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!)

        {
            (data, response, error) in

            if error == nil {

                var urlContent = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

                print(urlContent)

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){



                    self.webView.loadHTMLString(urlContent! as String, baseURL: nil) }

            }


         }

        task.resume()


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: I think you got problem with your network. You can try to load it with Safari and see how it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the website in a much simpler way:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.smartanalyzers.com") {
   webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
}
```

However when running this in iOS9 you need to disable Apple's App Transport Security for this website or it will not load, because it does not use HTTPS.

To allow HTTP loads from the website's domain you have to add this to your `Info.plist` file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>smartanalyzers.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

If you see that fonts or images are still not loaded correctly, check if they are loaded from different domains and add those domains to the `NSExceptionDomains` Dictionary in `Info.plist`